# Reading a csv file in Python then writing a new csv?

Tags: python, csv

I want to create a simple script that reads a csv file and then stores all the values in arrays based on the column.

My file looks like this:

```
Date, Store name, UPC, Price, Cost
2014-05-26, Toronto Store, 10000078, 2.99, 1.20
2014-05-26, Markham Store, 10000079, 3.25, 1.50
...etc
```

I want to store Dates in an array `dates[]`, name in `storenames[]`, etc.  I then want to take this information and stick it in a new csv file after some manipulation.

This is all I have so far:

```
import csv

cr = csv.reader(open("test.csv","rb"))
cw = csv.writer(open("newfile.csv", "wb"))
cw.writerow(["Date","Store Name","UPC","Price","Cost"])
```

Comment: Hey people, how about providing some constructive criticism to someone's first question instead of just marking it down.

Comment: Try breaking down the problem more.  Work on reading a file and show us what you're able to get and where you get stuck.  Then work on writing a file and show us what you're able to get and where you get stuck.  Until you show a little more "research effort" you're probably going to keep getting downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

The [python CSV module reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) may help

a code like

```
import csv

csvfile = open('test.csv', 'rb')
your_array = []
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    your_array += row
```

should do what you want, putting all your values into "your_array".

if you want to index the array by line and by word, you can use can change

```
your_array += row
```

to

```
your_array.append(row)
```

and index it by

```
your_array[line][position]
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the `DictReader` and `DictWriter` classes. These use the names from the first line in the file to turn each following line into a dictionary. You could then make your new columns by accessing the original's column names. You still need to do some form of "for all lines in csv" processing but the logic should be pretty easy.